# Discord.py Make the bot send something when wait_for answer is wrong

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make my bot send a message when the wait_for answer is wrong

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$greet'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Say hello!')

        def check(m):
            return m.content == 'hello' and m.channel == channel

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await channel.send('Hello {.author}!'.format(msg))
```

So when the user answer is not hello then the bot should send a message too

How to make this?

Comment: So, you want your bot to say something even if somebody writes "I love 007 films"? Very strange, but then you only have to avoid using the check, and then checking the content of the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting your `m.content` in your check function itself, you can instead call it outside of this using `msg.content`. This is because the variable `msg` is still a message object. Do view the revised code below.

```py
def check(m):
    # we won't check the content here...
    return m.author == message.author and m.channel == message.channel 
    
msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

# ...instead we will check the content using an if-else statement
if msg.content == 'hello':
    await message.channel.send("Hello {.author}!".format(msg))
else:
    await message.channel.send("You did not say hello...")
```

Some helpful documentation:

- [Python Conditions - w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp)
- [`wait_for` - discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)
- [`discord.Message` - discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message)